# Alter java security in docker container

Tags: java, docker, centos

I have oracle java sdk 8 running in my docker container (running centos 7) but I want to configure the security of running java apps. This can be done using jcontrol but it requires a graphical environment that my docker container does not provide. How can I solve this problem? thx

Answer (score 4):

Just edit the `java.security` file located in `<jvm_home>/conf/security` in your Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

In Dockerfile for 17 Java
#copy from source
COPY javaconf/java.security /app/javaconf/java.security

#next
COPY --from=build /app/javaconf/java.security /opt/openjdk-17/conf/security/java.security